# MySQL select both SUM and one specific row of the same column in one query - optimal way?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, subquery

Well, the question might not seem very smart, since I solve my problem. I'm just curious if there is better way. I wrote this query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(`attr`) AS `attrsum`, 
    (SELECT `attr` FROM `table`
     WHERE `id`=XXX AND `specialcondition`=YYY) AS `attr` 
FROM 
    `table` 
WHERE 
    `id`=XXX
```

It absolutely works and do what I want, but I'm not sure - is it the best way to do this? I mean subquery is still like another query, so I doubt that this is the optimized way to get those data. On the other hand - I have no idea how it can be done better. Or this is the best way and everything is fine in my query?

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: I'm currently on old 5.0.96. How does it matter?

Comment: MySQL 8 supports window functions.

Comment: I'm quite behind with this - just an autodidact working on old private server. The thing is, that I have a feeling, that I'm repeating myself im my query. But if You suggest that v8 might do this better, so on my v5 should be fine?

Comment: You can check the execution plan to see what is actually happening, but from what I can see it should require at worst two full table scans.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. In addition, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumming that the subquery is retrieving a single row, you can eliminate the subquery using MAX or MIN aggregate function together with CASE expression in this way:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(`attr`) AS `attrsum`, 
    MAX( CASE WHEN `specialcondition`=YYY THEN `attr` END ) as `attr` 
FROM `table` WHERE `id`=XXX
```

A speed gain will depend on the number of records in the table for a single ID, if it's only a few hundred records, it will be unnoticeable, for millions of records without an multicolumn index on `(id, specialcondition)` can be significant.
For the above query, a simple index on `id` column is sufficient.

Comment: Simple and clever, seems like exactly the thing that I tought, that exist, but couldn't figure out by myself :) THX!